# Como importar classes como HttpClient, DefaultHttpClient etc

Tags: android

Implementei essas classes, mas não consigo importá-las; o projeto foi feito no Android Studio.

```
public class HttpConnection {

    public static String getSetDataWeb(WrapData wd){
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(wd.getUrl());
        String answer = "";

        try{
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> valores = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            valores.add(new BasicNameValuePair("method", wd.getMethod()));
            valores.add(new BasicNameValuePair("produto", wd.getProduto()));
            valores.add(new BasicNameValuePair("marca", wd.getMarca()));
            valores.add(new BasicNameValuePair("detalhe", wd.getDetalhe()));
            valores.add(new BasicNameValuePair("img-mime", wd.getImage().getMime()));
            valores.add(new BasicNameValuePair("img-image", wd.getImage().getBitmapBase64()));

            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(valores));
            HttpResponse resposta = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            answer = EntityUtils.toString(resposta.getEntity());
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        return(answer);
    }

}
```

Comment: Não estou conseguindo importar. Apesar de declarar a importação, ele não acontece.

Comment: Importar não é o bastante. Ela estão no seu *classpath*? Onde você declarou a biblioteca Apache como dependência? Caso não tenha feito, veja na resposta como você pode fazer isso.

Comment: Não sei como fazer isso.

Comment: Veja na resposta abaixo a parte do `build.gradle`. Procure esse arquivo no seu projeto e adicione a linha mencionada onde tem as dependências.

Comment: Mas, caso use essa dependência, tenho que refazer meu código; você poderia editá-lo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minha questão consistia em conseguir importar a classe `HttpClient`. Realmente essa classe já é obsoleta, mas como já disse, pretendia aprender importá-la. Depois de algumas pesquisas descobri que deveria adicionar isto em meu `gradle`:

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Não é recomendado que se use mais a classe `HttpClient` por causa de algumas questões ligadas a performance (compressão, cache e redução de consumo de bateria).

Tanto que na versão 6, o `HttpClient` é obsoleta, como pode ser visto [aqui](https://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client). Ainda é possível usar, mas se for uma aplicação nova, é bom nem usar.

A recomendação é que se use ou um Client "third-party" como o `OkHttp` ou o próprio `UrlConnection`.

Ai seja pelo `OkHttp`:

#### Declarando a dependência no seu `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
```

#### Usando:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(URL)
        .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

if (response.code() != 200) {
    // ERRO
} else {
    String body = response.body().string();
    // Usar o body retornado pelo servidor...
}
```

#### Ou Usando `UrlConnection`:

```
private static String getUrlContents(String theUrl) {
    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        URL url = new URL(theUrl);

        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();

        BufferedReader bufferedReader =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

        String line;

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            content.append(line + "\n");
        }

        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        // Eh bom tratar as exceptions :D
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return content.toString();
}

String body = getUrlContents(URL);
// Usar o body retornado pelo servidor...
```

Comment: Você poderia editar meu código, colocando essa nova implementação?

Comment: Precisa mesmo? É bem simples encaixar, no caso do `UrlConnection` é só copiar a função nova e chama-lá

Comment: Cara, sou iniciante; peguei essa implementação para capturar imagem com a câmera do smartphone e enviar para o servidor. Mas achei muito complicado.